# SQL SELECT statement with a many-to-many extra table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that links users. Consider the following:

```
**Table contracts:**
   contract_id int,
   contract_number varchar,
   user_id int

**Table users:**
   user_id int

**Table user_links**
   user_id int,
   linked_user_id int
```

The user_links table can have 0 rows for a particular user_id, given the user doesn't have linked users, so a select statement can return either a row or NULL.

The approach with
`left join user_links ul on ul.user_id = contracts.user_id OR ul.linked_user_id = contracts.user_id` doesn't seem to work if there is no row in the user_links table.

Given only an int **user_id**, how can I get rows from the contracts table for both **user_id** AND **linked_user_id**?
For example, if the user_id 1 has a linked_user_id 2, I need the rows from contracts for both users; however, if the user doesn't have a row in user_links table, I still need to get their contracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input user_id is the variable @user_id, then the below query will get you all the contracts of that user, and if any linked user.

```
SELECT * from contracts c
where c.user_id = @user_id
OR c.user_id IN ( SELECT linked_user_id from user_links ul 
             WHERE ul.user_id = @user_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! I suggest a small edit though, after which it worked flawlessly. I forgot to check indexes on the table and it turned out that the primary key on the user_links table was linked_user_id and the user_id was a regular column.

Should anyone suffer from a similar nuisance, I did
`c.user_id = any(array(SELECT linked_user_id from user_links where user_id= @user_id)); `

Comment: Ok, you could accept the answer. You could add an index on the user_id column as well.

Comment: The consensus is that despite the index might prove useful, the database schema itself should probably remain untouched, as we've had to FULL VACUUM it multiple times now, lest the indexes turn to dust completely. This is a large database under a massive monolith service and will soon be out of operation.